# When typing "she said, \"don't\"" in the python shell why does it print 'she said, "don\'t"'

Tags: python

Type this directly into python shell.

```
"she said, \"don't\""
```

And press Enter, the result will be:

```
'she said, "don\'t"'
```

why does the former slash disappear and the latter slash appear between n and '?
Shouldn't the result be `'she said, \"don't\"'`?

Comment: They both disappear, you see the single quote escaped in the repr output because python outputs the string in single quotes so it has to escape any single quote in the string

Comment: Python outputs the string in single quotes _for this and similar strings_. Something like `"it's"` is displayed as-is.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the internal representation of a string object. The type of quote that's used to contain the string is arbitrary - it could be a single quote `'`, a double quote, `"`, or a triple quote `'''` or `"""`. Python generally prefers to enclose strings in single quotes, so sometimes it'll do that. The actual string's content, however, is the same. You can see this with `print()`.

```
>>> "she said, \"don't\""
'she said, "don\'t"'
>>> print("she said, \"don't\"")
she said, "don't"
>>> print('she said, "don\'t"')
she said, "don't"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you input something like `"she said, \"don't\""` into Python interpreter, Python construct a `String` object. Your input here is called a "string literal".

The same string object can be constructed by many means, string literal is only one of them, and you can [use different string literal to construct the same string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

The "String object" do not remember how it's constructed at all. That's why the output, which should be a representation of the string object, may be different from how it's constructed. And when your input and the output are the same, consider it a coincidence.

**UPDATE**

"String object"'s representations are all valid string literals. You can actually copy the output here, and feed it directly to input.

Since Python chose to represent the output here using single quote string literal, double quotes are not restricted, so do not need escaping. However, all single quotes, do need escaping. That's the most significant difference between single-quote and double-quote string literals.

Answer (score 0):

The actual contents of the string you typed is `she said, "don't"`. If you do `print("she said, \"don't\"")`, that's what you'll get. The quotes and slashes are just so you see a non-ambiguous representation of the string.